# Custom ajax not working in magento admin

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax

I have created custom module for store credits, for this I have used ajax which are working at frontend but when calling adminhtml controller using ajax at admin it returns 404 not found error.

My config.xml is here :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Assel_Customajax>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </Assel_Customajax>
    </modules>
    ...
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Assel_Customajax before='Mage_Checkout'>Assel_Customajax_Checkout</Assel_Customajax>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Assel_Customajax before="Mage_Adminhtml">Assel_Customajax_Adminhtml</Assel_Customajax>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
   ...
</config>
```

Ajax for calling controller at admin

```
new Ajax.Request("<?php echo Mage::getUrl('assel_customajax/adminhtml_credits/usecredits') ?>", 
{
    method: 'post',
    onComplete: function(result) 
    {
        ...
    }
});
```

I have created function in customajax/controllers/adminhtml/creditscontroller :

```
public function usecreditsAction()
{
   ...
}
```

But ajax return 404 not fount error.
How to call controller function successfully?

Comment: Quite a few syntax errors here which might be why you are not getting many replies, i.e. the url you are generating is wrong, you are not using the `adminhtml` helper to generate admin urls, controller name should be camelcase.  Check through everything, correct and you will probably find things to work.

Comment: Have you check error log when you try Ajax. Is there any things it show.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<admin>
   <routers>
      <adminhtml>
         <args>
            <modules>
               <Assel_Customajax before="Mage_Adminhtml">Assel_Customajax</Assel_Customajax>
            </modules>
         </args>
      </adminhtml>
   </routers>
</admin>
```

**EDIT**

```
new Ajax.Request("<?php echo Mage::getUrl('adminhtml/assel_customajax/adminhtml_credits/usecredits') ?>", 
{
    method: 'post',
    onComplete: function(result) 
    {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it is not working, and also return error in console "POST http://domain.com/index.php/storecredit/adminhtml_credits/usecredits/?isAjax=true 404 (Not Found)".

Comment: try with updated js code